# On the bisectors of the coordinate angles, find the points whose distance from the point M (-2, 0) is 10.

Tags: linear-algebra

If we assume that M has x, y coordinates and M1 has x1, x2 coordinates and I know the formula that the distance between two points d = sqrt((x1^2 - x^2) + (y1^2-y^2)). Then we get that x1^2 + y1^2 = 104 and can't go further than that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

The equation of the bisector will be $y=\pm x$

So, any point on the line $(a,\pm a)$

Now the distance $$10=\sqrt{(a+2)^2+(\pm a)^2}$$